# Child component is initialized before the parent

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have implemented a state container so that the parent page passes the state to 2 child components, and the child components can update the state and the parent will know about these changes. This is my state container (and it's registered as a singleton and injected into the parent and child components):

```
public class EditStateContainer
{
    public Entity Value { get; set; }
    public event Action OnStateChange;

    public void SetValue(Entity value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
        NotifyStateChanged();
    }
    private void NotifyStateChanged() => OnStateChange?.Invoke();
}
```

In the parent page I'm doing:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    stateContainer.OnStateChange -= StateHasChanged;
}

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    stateContainer.OnStateChange += StateHasChanged;

    //Create entity
    var entity = new Entity()
    {
        //Set properties here...
    };

    stateContainer.SetValue(entity);
}
```

And one of the child components:

```
protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
    if (!firstRender)
        return;

    entity = stateContainer.Value;
}
```

However, the child component's `OnAfterRender` is called before the parent's `OnInitialized`. Why is this happening and what is the correct order of events to use?

Comment: Instead of implementing your own state container, have you considered using Fluxor?

Comment: Also, based on what you're saying, you may want to consider using a cascading parameter.

Comment: @BlueEyedBehemoth A cascading parameter won't notify the parent that the child changed the parameter.

Comment: It would if you have a delegate in the object your passing down.

Comment: The order in which components render is in the hands of the Renderer.  However, I'm pretty sure that `OnAfterRender` on the child won't be called before `OnInitialized` is run on the parent.  Why?  Because for the renderer to know of the existence of the child, and thus that it needs to create it, it needs to run the `RenderFragment` that defines the content in the parent.  How are you asserting this?  I'm assuming that this is just some of the code?  It's probably the bits we can't see that are causing the problem.  Can you put together a minimum reproducible example?

Comment: My first question is-- why do you think `OnAfterRender` is called before the parent's `OnInitialized`?  No offense, but you say you've done a lot of things, without showing how you've done the things.  Where/how have you injected this service into your components?

Comment: Here's a sample repo: https://github.com/dbheale/BlazorSamples

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question, the child component doesn't initialize until its parent has initialized. I created a test project and logged all the steps that occurred.

Here's the heirarchy of what I created:

- Index

  - IndexChild1
  - IndexChild2

    - ChildsChild1

And the result:

```
BlazorTests.Pages.Index.OnParametersSetAsync(ParameterView: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ParameterView)
blazor.webassembly.js:1 BlazorTests.Pages.Index.OnInitialized()
blazor.webassembly.js:1 BlazorTests.Pages.Index.OnInitializedAsync()
blazor.webassembly.js:1 BlazorTests.Pages.Index.OnParametersSet()
blazor.webassembly.js:1 BlazorTests.Pages.Index.OnParametersSetAsync()
blazor.webassembly.js:1 BlazorTests.Shared.IndexChild1.OnParametersSetAsync(ParameterView: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ParameterView)
blazor.webassembly.js:1 BlazorTests.Shared.IndexChild1.OnInitialized()
blazor.webassembly.js:1 BlazorTests.Shared.IndexChild1.OnInitializedAsync()
blazor.webassembly.js:1 BlazorTests.Shared.IndexChild1.OnParametersSet()
blazor.webassembly.js:1 BlazorTests.Shared.IndexChild1.OnParametersSetAsync()
blazor.webassembly.js:1 BlazorTests.Shared.IndexChild2.OnParametersSetAsync(ParameterView: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ParameterView)
blazor.webassembly.js:1 BlazorTests.Shared.IndexChild2.OnInitialized()
blazor.webassembly.js:1 BlazorTests.Shared.IndexChild2.OnInitializedAsync()
blazor.webassembly.js:1 BlazorTests.Shared.IndexChild2.OnParametersSet()
blazor.webassembly.js:1 BlazorTests.Shared.IndexChild2.OnParametersSetAsync()
blazor.webassembly.js:1 BlazorTests.Shared.ChildsChild1.OnParametersSetAsync(ParameterView: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ParameterView)
blazor.webassembly.js:1 BlazorTests.Shared.ChildsChild1.OnInitialized()
blazor.webassembly.js:1 BlazorTests.Shared.ChildsChild1.OnInitializedAsync()
blazor.webassembly.js:1 BlazorTests.Shared.ChildsChild1.OnParametersSet()
blazor.webassembly.js:1 BlazorTests.Shared.ChildsChild1.OnParametersSetAsync()
blazor.webassembly.js:1 BlazorTests.Pages.Index.OnAfterRender(True)
blazor.webassembly.js:1 BlazorTests.Pages.Index.OnAfterRenderAsync(True)
blazor.webassembly.js:1 BlazorTests.Shared.IndexChild1.OnAfterRender(True)
blazor.webassembly.js:1 BlazorTests.Shared.IndexChild1.OnAfterRenderAsync(True)
blazor.webassembly.js:1 BlazorTests.Shared.IndexChild2.OnAfterRender(True)
blazor.webassembly.js:1 BlazorTests.Shared.IndexChild2.OnAfterRenderAsync(True)
blazor.webassembly.js:1 BlazorTests.Shared.ChildsChild1.OnAfterRender(True)
blazor.webassembly.js:1 BlazorTests.Shared.ChildsChild1.OnAfterRenderAsync(True)
```

Comment: "Scoped objects in Blazor seem to be the same as Singleton."  This will lead to much hilarity if you ever have more than one user on your site.    :D

Comment: No offense-- it's nice that you enjoy Fluxor, but that has nothing to do with the question.  The OP is trying to understand the Blazor lifecycle and trying to figure out how services work. Blazor supports services very well, and confusing someone with a 3rd-party recommendation really isn't helpful in this context.

Comment: Does Fluxor work well with Blazor Server?

Comment: [Polite] I agree with @Bennyboy1973 on this one.   I see you've tried Fluxor and posted another question as to why it doesn't work either.   You don't need Fluxor, just a properly coded State/Notification pattern implementation.   Have you looked at my answer below?

Comment: @blueeyedbehemoth -  Pose a question on here are to why "Scoped objects in Blazor seem to be the same as Singleton" and Benny, I or someone else will happily answer why.

Comment: I didn't realize that this was blazor server, but either way, I started the answer with the life cycle information. I'll remove irrelevant information

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 Scoped/Singleton act the same in Blazor WASM which is what I've been developing. Each user has their own environment.

Comment: I haven't used WASM, but since it's run on a client machine, then I can see that Singletone vs Scoped wouldn't mean much.  I'm curious if you authenticate as different users on different tabs if the singleton will introduce conflicts, or if every instance starts a new sandbox.  Shaun might know that, but I don't.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 each tab will have its own state, but they share the auth usually because they share the same cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my minimum reproducible example based on your code.  I've made a few mods and removed the stuff from `OnAfterRender` which I don't think you need there.  I also set the `EditStateContainer` as scoped as I'm assuming (maybe wrongly) it's per user session.

Have a look at it and change it to reproduce your problem.

```cs
public class EditStateContainer
{
    public Entity Value { get; set; } = new Entity();

    // Changed to EventHander as they are designed for muticast operations
    public event EventHandler? OnStateChanged;

    public void SetValue(Entity value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
        NotifyStateChanged();
    }
    private void NotifyStateChanged() 
        => this.OnStateChanged?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);
}

// my minimal Entity
public class Entity
{
    public string Value { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
}
```

My component:

```cs
@inject EditStateContainer stateContainer

<div class="bg-light m-2 p-2">
    <div class="alert alert-info">
        <h3>@(this.stateContainer.Value.Value)</h3>
    </div>

    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=UpdateState> Update State</button>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
        => stateContainer.OnStateChanged += OnStateChanged;

    private Task UpdateState()
    {
        this.stateContainer.SetValue(new Entity() { Value = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() });
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void OnStateChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        => this.InvokeAsync(this.StateHasChanged);

    public void Dispose()
        => stateContainer.OnStateChanged -= this.OnStateChanged;
}
```

And the test page:

```cs
@page "/"
@inject EditStateContainer stateContainer

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />
<Component/>
<Component />

<div class="alert alert-primary">
    <h3>@(this.stateContainer.Value.Value)</h3>
</div>

<div>
    <button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick=UpdateState> Update State</button>
</div>
@code {

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        // move to before setting the handler - it will get rendered correctly and setting it after will cause multiple renders
        stateContainer.SetValue(new Entity() { Value = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() });

        stateContainer.OnStateChanged += OnStateChanged;
    }

    private Task UpdateState()
    {
        this.stateContainer.SetValue(new Entity() { Value = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() });
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    // Invoke it to ensure it runs on the UI thread.  You can never be sure which thread the caller might be on.
    private void OnStateChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        => this.InvokeAsync(this.StateHasChanged);

    public void Dispose()
        => stateContainer.OnStateChanged -= this.OnStateChanged;
}
```